# $f(x)$ with real co-efficient and degree 2011 there is a real number $b$ such that $f(b)=f'(b)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Problem :

Verify if the statement is true or false -

For any polynomial $f(x)$ with real co-efficient and degree 2011 there is a real number $b$ such that $f(b)=f'(b)$ . (Here $f'$ means first derivative of $f$)

I think this false .

Reason : The question is asking whether or not there all real polynomial with degree 2011 has a multiple root $b$ .

So i think  $f(x)=(x-a_0)^0+...+(x-a_{2011})^{2011} $ where all of $a_0,a_1,a_2,\cdots a_{2011} \in \mathbb{R} $ , is good counter-example to the statement .

Is my counter-example a correct one?

Comment: That's correct. Then $f$ and $f'$ can't have common roots.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The statement is in fact true, because $f-f'$ is a polynomial with odd degree, so it must have a real root $b$.

For $b$ to be a double root, we would need $f(b)=f'(b)=0$, not just $f(b)=f'(b)$.

Comment: @Evan. Kindly clarify the statement about the double root. If (f - f')(x) has a double root at b then : (f -f')(x) = A(x - b)^2p(x) where p(x) is a polynomial of degree 2009. It follows (f' - f'')(b) = 0. How do you infer f(b) = f'(b) = 0 ? Thanks.

Comment: @PeterSzilas I did not infer that, please re-read